# Unlock screen appears after some delay

Tags: android, android-layout, countdowntimer

In my application, at the end I display a congratulation screen for 15 seconds which is a new activity containing a single image, then screen becomes black and then device gets locked.

Now immediately I click the unlock button so that unlock screen which prompt for password should come up. But only after unlock button is clicked **twice**(i.e. at least after 5 seconds), the password prompt appears.

What can be the reason for the delay in password prompt screen?

After some searching, I came across some links, which state *power saver mode activation* or *sd card mounting* could be reason for the delay. But if that was the case, than when I'm not using the app, how come device doesn't face the delay?

Any help appreciated.

**NOTE THAT** if I try pressing the unlock button after around 10 seconds of black screen appearance, unlock screen shows up immediately.

**FinalActivity.java**

```
public class FinalActivity extends Activity {
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.endenroll);
        MyCountDec c = new MyCountDec(15000, 1000);
        c.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        params1 = getWindow().getAttributes();
        params1.screenBrightness = -1;
        getWindow().setAttributes(params1);
        super.onResume();
    }


    public class MyCountDec extends CountDownTimer {
        public MyCountDec(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            params1 = getWindow().getAttributes();
            params1.screenBrightness = 0;
            getWindow().setAttributes(params1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like the lock screen of your device, not implemented by the app. Is that what you are asking about? If so, what device are you testing on?

Comment: Device is *Nook Color*. But this delay occurs only after black screen is displayed. Otherwise when I'm not using the app, unlock screen comes immediately.

Comment: if I try pressing the unlock button after around 10 seconds of black screen appearance, unlock screen shows up immediately

Comment: i am guessing that android waits for semething to happen and after your 10 seconds it simply timesout and returns to a defaulkt state.

Comment: Can u tell what u meant by *waits for semething to happen*?